# Como atualizar um select no html com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Sou novo em desenvolvimento e preciso de ajuda.
Tenho um select no html que preciso que seja atualizado quando selecionado dado de outro select.

Segue código html:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[name=camporegiao]').on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '../../FiltroFilial',
            data: 'idregiao=' + $('select[name=camporegiao]').val(),

            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert('Pagina não encontrada');
                },
                500: function () {
                    alert('erro no servidor')
                }
            },
            success: function (dados) {
                          $('select[name=campofilial]').refresh????;
                }
            }
        });
    })
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p>
   <b id="reg" name="reg">Região</b>
   </p>
   <select id="camporegiao" name="camporegiao" class="form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true">
   <% for(Regiao regiao: fdao.listarRegiao()){ %>
   <option value=<%=regiao.getId()%>><%=regiao.getRegiao()%></option>
   <% } %>
   </select>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row clearfix">
   <div class="col-md-3">
   <p>
    <b>Filial</b>
   </p>
   <select id="campofilial" name="campofilial" class="form-control show-tick" data-live-search="true">
   <% for(Filial filial: fdao.listarFilial()){ %>
   <option value=<%=filial.getId()%>><%=filial.getFilial()%></option>
   <% } %>
   </select>
  </div>
```

Não sei como fazer no javascript
Agradeço desde já

Comment: Talvez `$('select[name=campofilial]').html(dados)`?

Comment: Para sermos precisos na solução precisariamos ver como é o retorno do seu ajax, ou seja, qual o conteúdo retornado em dados. Mas como dito acima o caminho seria utilizando .html() ou similiar.

Comment: Olá 
Não deu certo
Consegui isso para atualizar a página inteira
window.location.reload();

Mas gostaria de atualizar apernas o select
$('select[name=campofilial]').location.reload();

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você terá de usar `Jquery`.

```
success: function (dados) {
  $('select[name=campofilial]').empty();
  $('select[name=campofilial]').html(dados);
}
```

Na linha de código acima, você deverá inserir os novos inputs que foram buscados pelo `ajax`. Na primeira coisa (`$('select[name=campofilial]').empty();`) você limpa o select da informação existente e na segunda linha insere os novos dados.

***NOTA:*** Na página `FiltroFilial` onde vai buscar os dados, cada dado tem que vir dentro de um `<option></option>`.

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado pelas ajudas

consegui da seguinte forma

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#camporegiao').on('change', function () {
        $("#campofilial").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '../../FiltroFilial',
            data: 'idregiao=' + $('#camporegiao').val(),
            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert('Pagina não encontrada');
                },
                500: function () {
                    alert('erro no servidor')
                }
            },
            success: function (dados) {
                filiaisfiltradas = dados.split(";");
                for (var i = 0; i < filiaisfiltradas.length; i++) {
                    var codfilial = filiaisfiltradas[i].split("-")[0];
                    var nomefilial = filiaisfiltradas[i].split("-")[1];
                    console.log(nomefilial);
                    $('#campofilial').append('<option value ="' + codfilial + '">' + nomefilial + '</option>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Mas acontece um problema
Quando abrem os dados aparece a listagem anterior mas quando clico aparece os dados que preciso.
Exemplo:

Listagem
A
B
C
D

Eu listei novo apenas
C
D

Mas continua aparecendo a listagem completa
E quando clico em A aparece C

Não sei como resolver